# Analogy of dd command real case when performing RW test

Tags: dd, disk, benchmark

I'm doing these two tests:

```
#1
dd if=/dev/zero of=./testfile1 bs=512M count=1 conv=fsync
```

And

```
#2
dd if=/dev/zero of=./testfile2 bs=1M count=512 conv=fsync
```

Can I say:

#1 is meaning copying (write perform) **1** big file with size **512M** and

#2 is meaning copying many small files **(512 files)** with size of every file is **1M**?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot say that. `dd` doesn't copy files, but the content of a single file, and these operations are very different, and not comparable in performance at all.

Answer (score 0):

No.

#1 is meaning copying a file in one big chunk

#2 is meaning copying a file in many small(er) chunks

I see three possible impacts to performance.

#1 requires the OS to free up 512M of memory for you, so you can read the file in.  This will slow it down.  (Using /dev/zero *might* allow the OS to make demand-zero pages which don't actually need the allocation, but that could  slow things down later...)  If this causes the dd process to swap, it will slow it down a lot.

#1 always tells the OS that it wants 512M of output disk allocation up front (since it only does one write).  This could make things faster if the OS and filesystem can do one huge allocation.  A good implementation of `dd` could tell the OS this before doing the writes, assuming the OS can so be told.  This could speed up #1 slightly, assuming the filesystem has the ability to do large allocations.  If you are writing to a raw device, this would not apply.

#2 makes 512 read requests and 512 write requests.  Switching into and out of the kernel, and validating parameters, takes time.  To see this impact, shrink the buffer size further (perhaps 4k or 16k -- though if you go too small, you start getting other serious performance impacts).

Answer (score 0):

> No, you cannot say that. dd doesn't copy files, but the content of a single file, and these operations are very different, and not comparable in performance at all.

1. You are creating a single large file named `testfile1` with a size of 512 megabytes. The data for this file is generated from `/dev/zero` (which provides null bytes)
2. The dd command, is creating a single file named `testfile2` and overwriting it with each iteration of the command. The `bs=1M count=512` options specify that the command should write data in 1 megabyte chunks, and it repeats this process 512 times. Each time the command is executed, it will generate a new set of null bytes (zeros) from `/dev/zero` and write them to the file, effectively overwriting its contents.

> The purpose of `conv=fsync` is to ensure data integrity and durability. It guarantees that the data is fully written to the storage medium and reduces the risk of data loss or corruption in case of power failures or system crashes. The sync operation ensures that any pending writes are committed to the storage device before the command finishes execution.

> Including `conv=fsync` ensures that the data you are writing with `dd` is reliably stored on the disk before the command completes. This can be important when you want to ensure that the data is successfully written and available for subsequent operations.